# Failed to stop mongodb.service while installing MongoDB on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, installation

While installing Mongodb I am facing error like

```
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
```

I tried to stop this service using-

```
~$ sudo systemctl stop mongodb
```

but it givs same error, I also check the status for mongodb using command

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

this will result following response

```
● mongodb.service

Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)

Active: inactive (dead)
```

I can install mongodb only after mongod.service get stoped, please guide how to stop service.

Comment: Do you have remainders of a failed installation of `mongodb`? Do you try to install from source or an Ubuntu package?

Comment: i dont have reminders of failed installation, I upgraded mongodb but it get crashed,so i decided to uninstall or reinstall it but the running service doesnt alow me to install it. i am tring to install mongodb from ubantu package

Comment: Add your answer to the question. An important point seems to be that an upgrade of mongodb failed. Did you upgrade it using a package for your distribution? Which distribution do you use?

Comment: i have problem while uninstall / install / repair not while upgrading

Comment: The information how you installed/upgraded `mongodb` might be important to give you instructions how to fix your problem. If the upgrade crashed it **is** a failed installation which might have left your system in an inconsistent state. If you don't answer the questions it will be difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command in terminal

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

After that check the status of service using

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

then you will be able to stop the service.

Comment: I tried it but its not working, it givs  'Failed to execute operation: Is a directory' as response

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the mongod.service first. Then enable and stop
[https://programmersought.com/article/28701054205/#:~:text=%2Flib%2Fsystemd%2Fsystem%2Fmongod.service](https://programmersought.com/article/28701054205/#:%7E:text=%2Flib%2Fsystemd%2Fsystem%2Fmongod.service)